# Client application that will only talk to an authenticated server using tls

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication, certificate-authority

I use Transport Layer Security (TLS) and I am building a prototype for a client application that will only talk to an authenticated server.Even if I wind up using certificates to authenticate the server, I should not use the same certificates to protect the communications channel and to authenticate the server.so :
"Should every application have its own certificate?" or there is another method to authenticate?  If I do need unique authentication. The number of keys I need scales directly with the number of clients. For ten clients this may not be a burden, but for ten-thousand it is challenging.
So :

How I will generate the keys?

How I will sign the keys: will I use a CA or make my own CA (and how I make it)?

How will the keys be distributed?

How will I handle key update, recovery, and replacement?

"Where are the certificates stored?"

Comment: Please provide some more information about your goal. Are you trying to ensure that third-party clients can't connect to your server? Are you trying to set up multiple servers? Do your clients need to support dynamic setup? Re-keying? Are you trying to have each client uniquely identify itself to one (or more) server(s)? Also, provide some information about the ecosystem: is this a mobile app, a desktop app, an embedded system, a specialized piece of hardware...? If you're making hardware, does it have a secure key store? Will your users be under some legal contract with you?

Comment: my equipments are network's equipment and I want the connection between this different equipments to be authenticated, so an equipment needs to be sure it is talking to the right equipment and not to a hacker who has revoked a certificate, so I want to generate my own CA and find answers for the other questions.